# AEM workflow comments duplicated by service users

Tags: aem, aem-6

If a user leaves a comment during a workflow, the comments are duplicated in the workflow comments section by service users for each `Auto Advance` step I have in the workflow model. Is there some way to not have these steps also create a comment? The `Show Non-User Comments` toggle doesn't hide these specific workflow comments.

Here's a bit of my workflow where the initiator is requested to make changes and can leave a comment when completing the step:

[image: Example workflow model]

Here is a comment left by my user `a a` in the `Workflow initiator changes requested` step, then duplicated by the service users in the following auto advance steps:

[image: Comments by users]

Answer (score 0):

Hi [klementine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/615743/klementine): What you've used above is not an `Auto Advancer` step, rather a `No Operation` step. Also, it wouldn't be correct to say that the comments are being "**duplicated**". The comments are rather being "**carried forward**". There's a small difference between the two statements here.

By definition a "No Operation" step does nothing. It is simply a placeholder step that will bring the workflow to a halt if `Handler Advance` checkbox is not checked. The comments are being copied from the previous step because it has been designed that way. The `No Operation` step is designed to not intervene in the workflow operation and keep the metadata intact. It will not delete any history metadata from workflow node.

Having said that, even if you use an `Auto Advancer` step, you will experience a similar behavior because the `Auto Advancer` step is also designed to just advance the workflow to the default next step in cases of `OR Splits`. It also doesn't alter the workflow metadata.

It's important that we understand the exact business requirement before designing our workflows. I don't feel that a `No Operation` step is really required in your case.